# Why does the script not run?

Tags: google-apps-script

After writing a script for a Google presentation, the script won't run.
The script is written in Dutch and starts with the following code:

}function maakGooglePresentatie() {
var presentation = SlidesApp.create

The 'execute' button is grey and cannot be used. What can be the cause?

Comment: Not sure if you posted your code incorrectly or if thats the problem but it should look something like this, could you confirm if thats the case for you?

`function maakGooglePresentatie() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.create("Your Presentation Title"); 
}`
Make sure youve saved the script, and selected ur funtion. You should be able to run it after you've done that.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem